# Understanding Erlang List Comprehension Generators

Tags: erlang, generator, list-comprehension

Given this function:

```
pretty_print(Folders, Depth) ->
    
        {CurrrentFolder, ListSubfolders} = Folders,
        SignTemp = lists:duplicate(Depth, "-"),
        case Depth of
            0 -> Sign = SignTemp;
            _ -> Sign = "|" ++ SignTemp
        end,
    
        io:format("~s~s~n", [Sign, CurrrentFolder]),
        
        [pretty_print(Subfolder, Depth+1)|| Subfolder <- ListSubfolders].
```

What happens to a recursive function in Erlang when in a list comprehension the generator is null or empty?

So when the variable is empty, the function won't call itself?

Won't it produce an error on that line? There is nothing to control that an error does not occur in this line?

```
  {CurrrentFolder, ListSubfolders} = Folders,
```

For example in this piece of code, the behaviour of another variable through Depth is controlled:

```
case Depth of
    0 -> Sign = SignTemp;
    _ -> Sign = "|" ++ SignTemp
end,
```

There is something that I do not quite understand here.

What happens to the function when it reaches the last folder of a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿What happens to a recursive function in Elrang when in a list comprehesion the generator is null or empty?

When a generator in a list comprehension is empty, then the comprehension is empty. Doesn't matter if it's recursive or not.

> So when the variable is empty, the function won't call itself?

Yes.

> There is nothing to control that an error does not occur in this line?

No, it simply assumes the caller will give an argument which matches it (and that `ListSubfolders` is a list each element of which also matches it). It would be more idiomatic to match directly in the head:

```
pretty_print({CurrrentFolder, ListSubfolders}, Depth) ->    
    SignTemp = lists:duplicate(Depth, "-"),
    ... %% the rest is the same
```

Comment: I have understood that, but I have many more doubts.

I think I will have to start with more basic things and step by step, because there are many things that I do not understand.

For example: What makes the function that when we reach the end of a folder that does not contain more folders, it calls itself again to explore another branch?

Comment: I comment to myself to explain the comment above about why I was confused by thinking of recursive function with iterative approach instead of recursive approach

In the end, I understood why the variable Depth behaves the way it does. And also because it did not stop the function from being called when it found folders that did not contain subfolders.

I was just thinking iteratively

Answer (score 1):

> What happens to a recursive function in Elrang when in a list
> comprehesion the generator is null or empty?

Easy to test:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

go(N) ->
    [go(X) || X <- [] ].
```

In the shell:

```
3> a:go(0).
[]
```

What would you expect the return value of the following to be:

```
[ X+1 || X <- [] ]
```

No different than if you defined:

```
f(X) -> X+1.
```

then executed:

```
[f(X) || X <- [] ]
```

The function doesn't get called if there is no argument to call the function with.

Comment: The example is very illustrative. I've already tried it. And I think it's a lesson learned.

However, I still have doubts about how the function can be called itself after exploring one of the branches of the directory to the end.

I will try to visualize the results in a directory with fewer folders, to see how it behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more clarity. Below code is not there for the purpose of control - they are **'just'** there because for root folder input, we do not want to put '|' character in the front of the folder name (cosmetic stuff). So even if you change it to whichever: `Sign = SignTemp` or `Sign = "|" ++ SignTemp` only, it won't change the logic.

```
case Depth of
    0 -> Sign = SignTemp;
    _ -> Sign = "|" ++ SignTemp
end,
```

In the previous code, `Folders` will never be `[]`, it will at least have the value of `{CurrentFolder, []}` (the one that could be an empty list is `ListSubfolders`).
And since below list comprehension is applied to `ListSubfolders`, it is safe because if `ListSubfolders` is `[]`, `pretty_print` will not be called.

```
[pretty_print(Subfolder, Depth+1)|| Subfolder <- ListSubfolders].
```

Comment: I thought you should define something like pretty_print ([], N) -> ...

Or maybe use some case Folder of []

But I see that it is not necessary.

I'll start learning more basic things ...

Comment: Updated the comment

Comment: With that added explanation I understand it a little better because it is not necessary to put any guard. I'm going to have to practice a lot and read, and above all, learn to think in the way that this language makes you think. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I draw this to illustrate how the list comprehension works, with all recursive call of your function pretty_print.
[image]

Comment: It has been very clarifying, that in the diagram is the call order 1-, 2-, 3 -, ... 14-.